# How to cut the last 3 values off a field in an SQL where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to compare a value from a field but only using the last 3 values.

```
WHERE table1.FieldValue(-3) NOT LIKE table2.Fieldvalue
```

obviously (-3) doesn't work. I've tried converting it to a string then trying to play with it that way. But to no success.

Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks

EDIT:

I'm looking at postcodes.

So table1.Fieldvalue = N90HXF
and table2.Fieldvalue = N90

I want to trim the HXF off so I can compare the two.

Comment: What is the field type?

Comment: Can you Show us a sample for better understanding?

Comment: `WHERE LEFT(table1.FieldValue, LEN(table1.FieldValue)-3)`

Comment: FYI, there doesn't appear to be a need for `LIKE` in this case - `=` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [LEFT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) function to compare only the first characters of a string, exluding the last 3 from the value.

```
WHERE LEFT(table1.FieldValue, LEN(table1.FieldValue)-3) NOT LIKE table2.FieldValue
```

As I would see things from your request, you **can exclude** the values which are less than 3 characters from the results, so you would just add another condition in your `WHERE` clause, like:

```
WHERE LEN(table1.FieldValue) > 3 
    AND LEFT(table1.FieldValue, LEN(table1.FieldValue)-3) NOT LIKE table2.FieldValue
```

But if you **do not want to exclude** those values from your result, but you would rather that they are added at the end of your query, you can use a condition like:

```
WHERE LEFT(table1.FieldValue, CASE 
            WHEN LEN(table1.FieldValue) < 3
                THEN table1.FieldValue + REPLICATE('', 3)
            ELSE LEN(table1.FieldValue) - 3
            END) NOT LIKE table2.FieldValue
ORDER BY LEN(table1.FieldValue) DESC
```

The above condition will pad (add) 3 whitespaces to all of your values, so that the LEFT() function will not result in an error even if the value has less than 3 characters.

Comment: I think he's looking for the exact opposite: `but only using the last 3 values.`

Comment: @YannickMeeus My bad, will adjust my answer.

Comment: @YannickMeeus Apparently he's looking for LEFT()

Comment: He could have clarified that a lot better in his requirement...My bad

Comment: I'm getting the problem Invalid Length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. Is this because of fields in the database being less than 3 long?